# How to read some part of text from url in android

Tags: android, xml, jsoup

I have content of a site and i want to read some text part of that what should i do ?

I have Jsoup Library but i don't know how to fetch this text with this library.

My contents that i want to read are like this

div class='clear'> 
  ایتنا- اداره کنندگان این صفحه هیچگونه ارتباط حقیقی یا حقوقی با دانشگاه آزاد اسلامی ندارند.

روابط عمومی دانشگاه آزاد در اطلاعیه ای اعلام کرد: صفحه فیسبوک منتسب به دکتر حمید میرزاده رییس دانشگاه آزاد اسلامی، از اطلاعات شخصی خود فراهم نکنند."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Elements mElements = doc.select("div[class^=clear]");
String text = mElements.get(0).text();
```

Comment: how could i find On Programming the Which divs has my favorite content ?

Comment: is this code works for img src ? I have another html like this <script src="/ClientScripts/swfobject.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> </script>
<div class="contentDetails">
<div id="ctl00_MainContentPlaceHolder_ContentDetailsBodyDivision" class="body">
<div align="justify">
<p> this is some text for test</P>
<p align="center"><img width="500" height="352" alt="MVM315" src="/UserUpload/Image/1(825).jpg" /></p>
<p align="center"><img width="500" height="352" alt="MVM315" src="/UserUpload/Image/2(598).jpg" /></p>
how can i get src="/UserUpload/Image/1(825).jpg" ??

Answer (score 0):

```
// Select divs whose class attribute starts with `clear`
Elements divs = doc.select("div[class^=clear]");
// Select the text of the first found div
String text = divs.get(0).text();
```

Comment: @user3453159 I don't know what is *your favorite content*. Also that is a new question so please ask another one.